# processing html drop down form

Tags: php, html

I have the following html drop down form:

```
<form method='post' action='signup.php'>$error

<span class='fieldname'>Sex</span>
<select name ="sex">
  <option value="female">Female</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
</select> <br />

_END;
```

But when I process the form in php I get a blank (no value) for $sex:

```
$sex = $_POST['sex'];
echo $sex;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you include this in a proper `<form>` environment and refer to the PHP script?

Comment: Not enough information. You are not showing anything related to the PHP that's processing the `form`, which is where the error is.

Comment: <form method='post' action='signup.php'>$error

<span class='fieldname'>Username</span>
<input type='text' maxlength='30' name='user' value='$user'
    onBlur='checkUser(this)'/><span id='info'></span><br />

<span class='fieldname'>Sex</span>
<select name ="sex">
  <option value="female">Female</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
</select> <br />
_END;

Comment: you don't echo $error in php code so i am not sure if you know how php scripts work but if you do the try to incldude </form> tag to end html form

Answer (score 0):

Give us more script.Perhaps some error.I used the below code and it worked fine.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sex']))
{
$sex = $_POST['sex'];
echo 'Result: '.$sex;
}
?>
<form method='post' action=''>
<span class='fieldname'>Sex</span>
<select name ="sex">
  <option value="female">Female</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
</select><input type="submit"> <br />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

option value so you must use `selected="selected"` any one. and try following code.

```
<form method='post' action=''>
<span class='fieldname'>Sex</span>
<select name ="sex">
  <option value="female" selected="selected">Female</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
</select><input type="submit"> <br />
</form>

<?php
       $sex = isset($_POST['sex']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sex']) : '';
       echo 'Gender: '. $sex;
?>
```